# Ruby On rails spree commerce installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

Hi friends am trying to bring spree commerce but i got error while am trying this command on windows 7 `spree install`

I got an error like this please help me ..

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse': (<unknown>): could not find 
expected ':' while scanning a simple key at line 17 column 3 (Psych::SyntaxError)
```

Comment: I don't really know why you got that error. But one thing I would try first is to upgrade to the latest ruby version 1.9.3. You are running 1.9.1.

Comment: thanks friend i wil change the version

Answer (score 0):

should have single space after : in database.yml,  for each line example

development:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: form_dev
  pool: 5
  username: user
  password: password
  host: localhost